# Can't mount external (USB 3.0) HDD

Tags: arch-linux, mount, usb-drive, usb-device

I'm trying to mount and format a Solid State Drive (SSD) hard-drive that's inside an USB hard-drive enclosure. When I connect the USB device, it gets recognized correctly, but I can't do anything with it. I'm not super familiar handling USB devices via the CLI, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

The drive is recognized correctly (it's `/dev/sda`):

```bsh
[x80486@archbook:~]$ udisksctl status 
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Force MP500               E7FM04.C  18097957000123397721 nvme0n1 
SABRENT SABRENT           0204      DA89765&1312B        sda

[x80486@archbook:~]$ lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT
NAME        LABEL MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1           
├─nvme0n1p1       
├─nvme0n1p2       /
└─nvme0n1p3       /home

[x80486@archbook:~]$ fsck -N 
fsck from util-linux 2.36
[/usr/bin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2 
[/usr/bin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /home] fsck.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p3

[x80486@archbook:~]$ sudo lvs --all 
[x80486@archbook:~]$ sudo vgs --all 
[x80486@archbook:~]$ sudo pvs --all 
  PV             VG Fmt Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1          ---     0     0 
  /dev/nvme0n1p1        ---     0     0 
  /dev/nvme0n1p2        ---     0     0 
  /dev/nvme0n1p3        ---     0     0
```

If I try to mount it manually, it fails:

```bsh
[x80486@archbook:~]$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda 
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda is not a mountable filesystem.

[x80486@archbook:~]$ sudo mount /dev/sda /home/x80486/Temporal/tmp_mount/ 
mount: /home/x80486/Temporal/tmp_mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Is there anything I'm missing? The SSD was used before on laptop with Ubuntu.

> I'm using Arch Linux `Linux uplink 5.4.54-1-lts #1 SMP Wed, 29 Jul 2020 21:38:41 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: A few questions - what's the expected file-system (try including output from `fsck -N`)? Is it encrypted? If not it's possible you aren't mounting it with the right driver (missing package or simply not specified). You say it was used before on Ubuntu -- does it still work there? If you'd prefer to get it working with your DE try here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_manager_functionality

Comment: can you provide output of ```lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT```?

Comment: either there is partition as @Jansen suggest, try using `/dev/sda1` (altough it should be showned on output of lsblk), otherwise drive was used by lvm, can you show output of `pvs` , `vgs`, `lvs` ?

Comment: Nothing useful for those commands. There is no partition, which is really weird. I can't remember if by default, Ubuntu uses LVM or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I'm missing? The SSD was used before on laptop with Ubuntu.

The disk is almost certainly partitioned.

you probably want to interract with /dev/sda1 (or some other number) not with /dev/sda